# pyspark calculate average/sum of multiple columns, ignoring null values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data frame like this.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

cols=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
find_mean =  F.expr('+'.join(cols))/len(cols)

data=[(
    1,2,3,4,5,None
),(
    1,2,3,4,5,None
),(
    5,4,3,2,1,None
),
(3,4,5,1,2,5)]

schema=T.StructType([
    T.StructField('a',T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('b',T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('c',T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('d',T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('e',T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('f',T.IntegerType())
])

test=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
sum=test.withColumn('average',find_mean)
sum.display()
```

my data looks like this after creating a "average" column, but some values are null because there are null values in f column.

```
a|b|c|d|e|f   |average|
1|2|3|4|5|null|null
1|2|3|4|5|null|null
5|4|3|2|1|null|null
3|4|5|1|2|5   |3.3333
```

I want my data to look like this.

```
a|b|c|d|e|f   |average|
1|2|3|4|5|null|3
1|2|3|4|5|null|3
5|4|3|2|1|null|3
3|4|5|1|2|5   |3.3333
```

I'd like to keep null values as they are in "f" column--prefer not to fill null values with zeros but in the "average" column, I'd like to have valid numbers/decimals.

How can I make it work?

Comment: are you using `databricks` ?

Comment: Yes, i‘m using databricks.

Answer (score 1):

Since Spark 3.1, you can filter your array to remove null values before computing the average, as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
filtered_array = F.filter(F.array([F.col(i) for i in cols]), lambda c: F.isnotnull(c))
find_mean = F.aggregate(filtered_array, F.lit(0), lambda acc, c: c + acc) / F.size(filtered_array)
```

So when you execute the following code, with `test` being the dataframe you defined in your question:

```py
sum = test.withColumn('average', find_mean)
sum.show(truncate=False)
```

You get the following result:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+----+------------------+
|a  |b  |c  |d  |e  |f   |average           |
+---+---+---+---+---+----+------------------+
|1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |NULL|3.0               |
|1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |NULL|3.0               |
|5  |4  |3  |2  |1  |NULL|3.0               |
|3  |4  |5  |1  |2  |5   |3.3333333333333335|
+---+---+---+---+---+----+------------------+
```